# ERROR: *use of undeclared identifier 'firstObject' on a NSArray on an iOS 7 project

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController     = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
NSArray *arrayViewControllers                  = (NSArray *)splitViewController.viewControllers;

ViewController *masterViewController           = (ViewController *) arrayViewControllers[firstObject];
VideoViewController *detailVideoViewController = (VideoViewController *) arrayViewControllers[lastObject];
```

**ERROR: *use of undeclared identifier 'firstObject'**

**ERROR: *use of undeclared identifier 'lastObject'**

what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `firstObject` and `lastObject` are properties of NSArray.
You can't use it as subscript.

Either use it as:

```
ViewController *masterViewController           = (ViewController *) [arrayViewControllers firstObject];
VideoViewController *detailVideoViewController = (VideoViewController *) [arrayViewControllers lastObject];
```

or:

```
ViewController *masterViewController           = (ViewController *) arrayViewControllers.firstObject;
VideoViewController *detailVideoViewController = (VideoViewController *) arrayViewControllers.lastObject;
```

Refer [NSArray Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSArray/firstObject) for more information